# ART error message while working with AsynchTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, art-runtime

I am getting a weird error massege while working with AsynchTask, and I am not sure what it refers to.

Here is the error log:

```
E/art: Thread[31,tid=13078,WaitingForDebuggerSend,Thread*=0xb711bb58,peer=0x12c007c0,"AsyncTask #2"] suspend count too deep for method invocation: 2
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 711005(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 21MB/29MB, paused 2.929ms total 135.052ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 423095(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 21MB/36MB, paused 4.272ms total 147.504ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 87.501ms for cause HeapTrim
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.414ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.127ms
```

I do **not** experience anything bad, but still it is an error. **Should I pay attention to this?** Can someone explain what this refers to?

Basically what I do is executing an AsynchTask in every 20 seconds, like this:

```
if (request != null) {
    request.cancel(true);
}
if (requestListener == null) {
    request = new Request(context);
} else {
    request = new Request(context, requestListener);
}
request.execute(unlockUrl);
```

Comment: That is not an error message, its the Garbage Collector!

Comment: But why is it an error log then? Please check the first line of the log.

Comment: Because your log level must be allowing it, here, read up on [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html)